# 32bit/64bit issue when working with Numpy and petsc4py

Tags: petsc, numpy

When indexing PETSc.Mat `A` with an array `c` ( `numpy.ndarray` with `dtype('int64')`), I run into the following error:

```
  File "/Users/cls/workspace/LAMG-Python/src/lamg/amg/setup.py", line 945, in buildInternal
    Acc = A[c, c]
  File "Mat.pyx", line 185, in petsc4py.PETSc.Mat.__getitem__ (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:71407)
  File "petscmat.pxi", line 862, in petsc4py.PETSc.mat_getitem (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:22442)
  File "petscmat.pxi", line 773, in petsc4py.PETSc.matgetvalues (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:21226)
  File "arraynpy.pxi", line 123, in petsc4py.PETSc.iarray_i (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:5284)
  File "arraynpy.pxi", line 117, in petsc4py.PETSc.iarray (src/petsc4py.PETSc.c:5192)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I assume there is a simple solution (allowing the cast, making everything  32 or 64 bit...). Can you point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: oops, just noticed this question languishing on the petsc4py mailing list :(

Comment: Yeah, I thought it must be a really stupid question if nobody cares to answer. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two solutions, depending on what you want.  As a point of information, PETSc [defaults to 32-bit indexing](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#with-64-bit-indices) on normal builds.

If you **always want** 64-bit indices, then you should configure and build PETSc with 64-bit indices (pass `--with-64-bit-indices` to configure) and everything will work fine.

On the other hand, if you would like to explicitly force a copy if needed every time you hand a data structure to PETSc, you can do this by  `c.astype(petsc4py.PETSc.IntType)`.  See [this question on StackOverflow for more on the intricacies of doing/avoiding a Numpy copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389517/in-place-type-conversion-of-a-numpy-array).

Comment: What would you recommend? If numpy defaults to 64-bit , I think I should rebuild PETSc with 64 bit indices. I doubt that my matrices will be large enough that the integer size becomes a concern.

Comment: I'd instantiate the index arrays in numpy using the `petsc4py.PETSc.IntType` data type, which will increase your code coupling to `petsc4py`, but avoid the need for doing a copy if you otherwise don't care about integer type.